# Angular UI-Calendar external event renderer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, calendar

I'm very new to Angular, and I'm using the Angular UI-Calendar to display bookings, which are events that are slightly more detailed than the regular events.  I can see how I can render these events directly in the render function, but obviously this isn't the best way to do this, and really want to be able to have an external renderer for events, and also be able to have a renderer suitable for the different types of calendar view.

This is what I currently have, and is more basic than it will ultimately be.  In the eventRender section I really want to be able to call/include another angular html template that is sole responsible for rendering events.

```
eventRender : function(event, element) {
                element.attr({
                    'tooltip' : event.title,
                    'tooltip-append-to-body' : true
                });
                angular.forEach(event.bookings, function (booking, key){
                    $(element)
                      .append('<strong>' + booking.title + '</strong>')
                      .append(' x').append(booking.numberCustomers)
                      .append(' &dash; ').append(booking.contact)
                      .append('<br />');
                });

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per UI-Calendar documentation for **eventRender** method:

> The function can also return a brand new element that will be used for
>   rendering instead. For all-day background events, you must be sure to
>   return a .

This lets you return different layouts for different events in your schedule.

First, add a custom class to each eventSource, like this:

```
var event = {
  ...
  className: 'booking-1'
};
```

Then, in eventRender method return html based on the class attached to an event:

```
eventRender : function(event, element, view) {
  if ( event.className.indexOf('booking-1') > -1 ) {
    return '<span>1</span>';
  } else if ( event.className.indexOf('booking-2') > -1 ) {
    return '<span>2</span>';
  }
}
```